# How do I add a Response Handler to Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.HttpConfiguration as part of WCF Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf-web-api

I've an ASP.NET MVC project, where I use the WCF Web Api (Preview 6), and I want to use this to support a simple JSON service that supports JSONP. The JSON part of the service I got up and running pretty easy, but I've got some problems with the JSONP part of it.

Based on Alexander Zeitler's excellent [post](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2011/07/26/Look-Ma-I-can-handle-JSONP-%28aka-Cross-Domain-JSON%29-with-WCF-Web-API-and-jQuery!.aspx), I got the idea to use a Response Handler to support JSONP with the callback parameter, but I can figure out how to add this response handler to the HttpConfiguration (with WCF Web Api Preview 6).

My code in Global.ascx.cs looks something like this:

```
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);        
var config = new HttpConfiguration() { EnableTestClient = true };

config.MessageHandlerFactory = () => container.GetExportedValues<DelegatingHandler>();

//config.ResponseHandlers <-- what to do here???
```

The message handler factory takes care of explicitly returning a JSON requests when using the /json in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at how Phil Haack implemented the [Authorize] attribute using the Web Api.
[Implementing an Authorization Attribute for WCF Web API](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/19/implementing-an-authorization-attribute-for-wcf-web-api.aspx)

In that example he appends an additional (custom) handler.  I'm sure you could use the same code to replace an existing handler.